# Setting a Terminal Command to run in Crontab

Tags: node.js, linux, cron

I'm trying to set a CRON Job that runs @ 12 Midnight every day. The below code runs the task

```
node command.js sample
```

I'm using crontab for this. Please have a look at the below line

```
00 00 * * * node command.js sample
```

Should I write a .sh file or is there a simple way to run this. Thought of getting some expert opinions

Comment: yes i do have made one with crontab -e

Comment: You do't have to create it via script, the above looks good enough. And if you want to disable the auto-generated mail entries after every run, you can add `MAILTO=""` after the actual line

Comment: Disabling auto-generated mails for success is good to avoid success-alert-fatigue. However, consider using a fail-alert service like the one we've created at http://wdt.io so that you're aware if/when the job fails.

Answer (score 0):

There can be some problem, as cron job does not call .bash_profile or .bash_rc. If you have any environment variable, that will not initialized

Try something like,
00 00 * * * source /home/username/.bash_profile;

Refer this link:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67940/cron-ignores-variables-defined-in-bashrc-and-bash-profile